# Why VSCode enters infinite loop showing "extesion is disabled, would you like to enable and open the url?"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-remote, vscode-remote-ssh

I develop an extenison and register onUri to receive the url "vscode://<extensionid>/".  I publish the extension to the marketplace. When I open url in my webbrowser, the VSCode will be opened and ask me if need to install the extension.
But when I open an remote ssh window (I connect to remote cloud environment) and then open the url in browser, I receive "Extension xx is disabled, Would you like to enable the extension and open the url". I choose "enable" and then after few seconds, the same message occurred again!! It enters to infinite loop……

So I want to ask:

1. Is a VSCode bug?
2. How to solve it? Can I in some way make my extension enable in both local and remote?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the extension kind is 'workbench':

1. VSCode 1.57.1 ，the infinite loop will occur, I think it is a bug
2. VSCode 1.65.2 , this problem does not exist

When the extension kind is 'ui', this problem does not exist in both 1.57.1 and 1.65.2

So, I finally solved it by adding this to package.json

```
    "extensionKind": ["ui"]
```